# Wordpress filter by custom type

Tags: wordpress, custom-post-type

I am trying to make an index page but just showing the posts of a specific custom type.

Loop starts like this:

```
 <?php while ( have_posts() ) : the_post() ?>
```

How can I modify the code just to show posts from a custom type called "classifieds"?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'd be much better off creating your own query, and by-passing the post type check altogether;

```
query_posts('post_type=my_post_type');
while (have_posts()):
    ...
endwhile;
```